# Imacros Javascript eval code not working

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to extract all the links from a div with imacros and eval javascript but my code is not good what I do wrong ?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=dir:ltr Extract=Htm

Set !Var1 Eval("var x = '{{!extract}}';x.match(/href="([^\'\"]+)/g); x[1];") 
PROMpT {{!VAR1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract as follows:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=dir:ltr EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/href=\"(.+?)\"/g).join('\\n').replace(/(href=|\")/g, '');")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```